# react query refetches before mutation are executed

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I started using react query mutations but I found out when looking at the network request that when I call a mutation it first fetches before executing it.

Here is my mutation

```
 const mutation= useMutation(
    async (values: VoteProps) => {
      await fetch("/api/test/test", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
    },
     onSettled: (data: any, error: any, variables: any, context: any) => {
      refetch();
    },
}
```

This is my useQuery

```
  const { isLoading, isError, data, error, refetch } = useQuery<test>(
    "test",
    test,
    { refetchInterval: 30000, refetchIntervalInBackground: true }
  );
```

The mutation changes the test useQuery values

Is there a reason for it or a way to disable that?

thank you

Comment: It probably just invalidates because you focus the window.

Comment: @TkDodo when testing I do not leave the page and I have the refetchIntervalInBackground so it refetches every 30s whatever I am in focus or not

Answer (score 3):

Returning the fetch in your mutation function will solve the problem.

**Explanation**

The mutation function should return a promise-like value. `useMutation` waits until this promise gets either resolved or rejected and then calls the `onSettled` callback.

your mutation function is a void function, so This is what happens when you call the `mutation.mutate()`:

1. `useMutation` calls the mutation function
2. `fetch()` is called **asynchronously**
3. the mutation function returns immediately with `undefined` value
4. `useMutation` calls the `onSettled` callback because the mutation function has returned something. (although the `fetch` has not yet been resolved)
5. query gets **refetched**
6. the mutation and query requests get response from the server some moments later